# How to create windows installer for my 3rd party plugin?

Tags: windows, installation

I want to create an installer MSI that will unload and move files I need for my plugin into the user's application folder. In my case the application is Cinema 4D, but this detail does not matter. I need to unload a .cyc file and place it in a specific subfolder under the application folder. In addition to that, I need to add a line of code to a .res file another subfolder of the application.

I want my installer to look nice

I have already looked at WIX, NSIS, Advanced Installer and Microsoft Visual Studio as possible options but do not know how to do what I have to do. I've seen installers that do exactly this - so how do I do this?

Comment: Your question is very broad and in reality you ask multiple questions. Try to be more concrete, then it is also more easy to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the tools mentioned above should be able to help you get the job done, except Visual Studio (its support for building setup packages is quite limited).

Here is a [step by step article](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-another-application.html) explaining how to do this with Advanced Installer. You can download a trial version of Advanced Installer from the website, during trial you can access all the features.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*

Comment: Cool, almost perfect. Now how do I set up Advanced Installer to add a line of code to the .res file like I need?

Also are there any limitations to the free version of the software?

Comment: The free version gives you access only to the features available in a "Simple" project type, as shown in this tutorial: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html.

Updating the contents of a file is not possible with the free edition. For that you need a commercial edition, where you can integrate your own C# DLL or PowerShell scripts to perform custom operations (like appending text in your .res file)